# how to assign a list of values to a python netcdf4 variable object?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am trying to use the netCDF4 package with python.  I want to do something which I think should be straightforward, but I can't make it work and I can't find any documentation on it.  I have a list, and I simply want to store the list in a netCDF4.Variable object.  I thought this code would store "newlist" in the netCDF4.Variable object "x_data", which is a component of the Dataset object "netdata":

```
netdata.variables['x_data'][:]=numpy.array(newlist)
```

But it's no go.  I get the error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

BTW, I *have* imported both netCDF4 and numpy.  Also BTW, this is the same error I get if I do this without converting newlist to a numpy array.

Surely there's a way to do this.  Anyone know how?  Thanks.

Addendum: This simple change gets me past the error message:

```
netdata.variables['x_data']=newlist
```

But I'm still not out of the woods.  The data definitely gets stored in netdata.variables['x_data'], but then I close netdata and exit python, and examine the netCDF output, and the data just isn't there.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, if anyone is interested, apparently the way to do it is:

```
netdata.variables['x_data'][:]=newlist[:]
```

Hint to anyone who might be working on the netCDF4 python package: It's a great package in many ways, but I couldn't find this anywhere in the documentation.